# Extract a thumbnail from a specific video frame

Tags: ffmpeg

Given a specific frame I need to extract an image (a thumbnail) from a video using ffmpeg.

E.g. I can do:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ss 00:01:14.35 -vframes 1 out2.png
```

I can extract an image from a specific time (00:01:14.35), but what I need is to extract an image from a specific frame.

Comment: What do you mean by specific frame?

Comment: Hope [this link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video) may help.

Comment: I mean the frame 866 or 1350 of the video.

Comment: It's duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/459313/how-to-cut-at-exact-frames-using-ffmpeg isn't it?

Comment: @ptQa No! This isn't a duplicate!

Answer (score 50):

To get to some specific frame you should use filter select. Command to extract frame 100 out of video should look like this:

```
 ffmpeg -i in_video.avi -vf "select=gte(n\,100)" -vframes 1 out_img.png
```

Comment: You can also pipe the result to `stdout`, which is useful if you call `ffmpeg` from another process: ```ffmpeg -i sample_video.mp4 -vf "select=gte(n\,100)" -vframes 1 -f image2pipe pipe:1 | cat > my_img.jpg``` - however, I did not manage yet to output another format than `jpg`.

Comment: I guess here 100 is 101th frame because it starts from 0.

Answer (score 7):

Use the following method

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:10:20 -t 1 -s 400x300 -i <INPUT_FILE> -f mjpeg <OUTPUT_FILE>
```

-ss and the time argument that follows tells ffmpeg at what point you want the screenshot snapped. In this example, ffmpeg will take a shot at the 10 minute and 20 second point. -t tells ffmpeg that you want only 1 shot, -s is the size of the pic, and -f tells it to make a photo (but not limited to jpg).
For example, to generate a png screenshot for Batman.avi at the 1 hour, 12 minute, and 30 second point:

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:12:30 -t 1 -s 400x300 -i Batman.avi -f mjpeg Batman.png
```

Comment: that -f mpeg option increases the size of the extracted images dramatically. You can omit it

Comment: In question said, by frame, not by time!

Answer (score 0):

or just

```sh
-vf "select=eq(n\,100)" 100.png
```

the `-vframes` option could be omitted